# Field orderRepository in app.service.OrderService required a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' that could not be found

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data

I am trying to create REST API Service with Spring. I have following structure and classes

```
app\
├── controller\
│   └── OrderController.java\
├── dto\
│   └── OrderDto.java\
├── model\
│   └── Order.java\
├── repository\
│   └── OrderRepository.java\
├── service\
│   ├── IOrderService.java\
│   └── OrderService.java\
└── Application.java
```

Order.java

```
    @Entity @Table(name = "order")
    @JsonAutoDetect(fieldVisibility = JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY)
    public class Order {
    //getters, setters, constructors
```

OrderController.java

```
    @RestController
    public class OrderController {
        @Autowired
        private IOrderService orderService;
    //some code
```

IOrderService.java

```
    public interface IOrderService {
        List<Order> findAll();
    }
```

OrderService.java

```
    @Service
    public class OrderService implements IOrderService {
        @Autowired
        private OrderRepository orderRepository;
    
        @Override
        public List<Order> findAll() {
            return (List<Order>) orderRepository.findAll();
        }
```

OrderRepository.java

```
    @Repository
    public interface OrderRepository extends JpaRepository<Order, UUID> {
    }
```

Application.java

```
    @SpringBootApplication
    @EnableJpaReposotories(basePackages = "app.repository")
    public class Application {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
        }
    }
```

AppConfig.java

```
    @Configuration
    public class AppConfig {
        @Bean(name="entityManagerFactory")
        public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
            LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
            return sessionFactory;
        }
    }
```

application.properties

```
    spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
    spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:8080/postgres
    spring.datasource.username=postgres
    spring.datasource.password=postgres
```

build.gradle

```
    dependencies {
        implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
        implementation 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.26'
        implementation 'org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:3.0.3'
        implementation 'org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:3.0.3'
        implementation 'jakarta.persistence:jakarta.persistence-api:3.1.0'
        implementation 'org.springframework:spring-context:6.0.6'
        runtimeOnly 'org.postgresql:postgresql'
        testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    }
```

It seems repository isn't visible for service. I've tried to add some annotations to Application class (such as @EnableJpaRepositories(base_packages = {"app.repository"})), but there similar error.
How can I handle this?
UPD - Now the message is **Field orderRepository in app.service.OrderService required a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' that could not be found**

Comment: Try @EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "app.repository.*")

Comment: Your repository must extend JpaRepository (not CrudRepository) to be auto-configured as such.

Comment: Your dependencies could cause the issues with auto-configuration of Spring Boot Data JPA. I recommend to use the gradle file configured with https://start.spring.io/

Comment: Remove `spring-context`, the `org.springframework.data` dependencies and `jakarta.persistenc-api` one. add `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` instead. Also remove your `AppConfig` that breaks (parts of) the auto configuration of Spring Boot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Your dependencies are too verbose, use `spring-boot-sarter-data-jpa` instead of the individual dependencies.
2. Remove `AppConfig` as that breaks (partially) the Spring Boot auto configuration, or at least the `LocalSessionFactoryBean`.
3. The `@Repository` on the Spring Data repository doesn't add anything but noise and clutter
4. You don't need `@EnableJpaRepositories` assuming your `@SpringBootApplication` annotated class is in a top level package.

```
dependencies {
  implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
  implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
  implementation 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.26'
  runtimeOnly 'org.postgresql:postgresql'
  testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}
```

```java
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {
  // Removed LocalSessionFactoryBean
}
```

```java
package app;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
  }
}
```

```java
public interface OrderRepository extends JpaRepository<Order, UUID> {}
```

**PRO-TIP**: Use constructors for dependency injection instead of fields.

```java
@Service
class OrderService implements IOrderService {

  private final OrderRepository orderRepository;
    
  OrderService(OrderRepository orderRepository) {
    this.orderRepository=orderRepository;
  }
  // Rest of methods omitted
}
```

Ofcourse you can do the same for your controllers.

Answer (score -1):

@Repository annotation is missing.

```
@Repository
public interface OrderRepository extends CrudRepository<Order, UUID> {
}
```

Comment: Added annotation, @EnableJpaReposotories(basePackages = "app.repository"), changed CrudRepository to JpaRepository. Now I get similar error but now there is required a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' that could not be found

Comment: @Bean(name="entityManagerFactory")
public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
    LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();

    return sessionFactory;
} 

Try to add this in config class. If you don't have any configuration class, create a class and annotate it with @Configuration class and add this method.

Comment: Now I am getting java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type org.hibernate.SessionFactory not present. Should I add any depedency to build.gradle?

Comment: do you have repo, if yes share the link please. I can check

Comment: no, i don't have

Comment: dependencies {
    // other dependencies ...
    implementation 'org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.5.7.Final'
}

try to add this

Comment: Did it, fix your issue? if yes, please accept this answer.

Comment: No, didn't resolved yet. Now I am getting this error
UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'orderService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'orderRepository': Error creating bean with name 'orderRepository' defined in app.repository.OrderRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on Application: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'jpaSharedEM_entityManagerFactory' while setting bean property 'entityManager'

Comment: `@Repository` on an spring data repository is useless.